# Open multiple gnuplot windows with qt capabilities

Tags: gnuplot

Is there a way to open more than one window in gnuplot with all the windows having full qt capabilities?

I know that using `set terminal qt <number>` I can have more than one window opened at the same time. But I can only zoom, pan and drag my plot in the last one and I want to be able to do so in all the plots.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: No, that isn't possible

Comment: @Christoph too bad :(